# Convert Text into boolean expression in C#

Tags: c#

i have a project to create a boolean table (incidence matrix) for an information retrieval system, so i created 3 files and i took the words from each file and removed the stopping words from them, and added them to a listView using c# language, and all i need is to be able to take the query from a textBox and convert it into a suitable boolean expression so that it will return the names of documents that the satisfies the boolean expression.
eg. "Ahmed and love and not ali"
This should give me Ahmed && love && ! Ali which will be true for doc1.

[image]

Comment: Google for "parser". Maybe you'll find an existing library for boolean expression parsing. If not, write your own. You may use a parser generator like ANTLR.

Comment: @Ahmed Are you going to support parenthesis?  Double, triple, etc. negations?

Answer (score 2):

Using String.Replace

```
    string src = "Ahmed and love and not ali";
    string res = src.Replace("and", "&&")
                    .Replace("not", "!");
    string[] parts = res.Split(' '); // { Ahmed , && , love , && , ! , ali }

    //Do Shunting-Yard algorithm to convert infix expression to postfix
    ToPostfix(parts); // Ahmed love && ali ! &&
    bool result = PerformRPN(parts); //Calculate postfix, you should read the Reverse Polish Notation article
```

Link to the wikis (updated the shunting-yard reference to a closer version to the OP problem):
[Shunting-Yard algorithm](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2011/12/11/the-shunting-yard-algorithm/)
[Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

There are a few key concept in the algorithm that i'll explain further

- **IsOperator**

> bool IsOperator(string part) {return part=="&&" || part=="||" || part == "!" || ...}

- **IsOperand** - is not Operator

If you need anymore help, let me know

**Extra:** (as Jared suggest)
You should initialize your table value in a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, bool> doc1 = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
doc1.Add("Ahmed", doc1BooleanArray[0]);
doc1.Add("love", doc1BooleanArray[1]);
...
```

So when you need to get your operand value to calculate expression just use:

```
//Get operand_part = "Ahmed"
bool val = doc1[operand_part]
```

Comment: hmm? if you're gonna give a thumb down, why dont leave a comment explain the reason why ?

Comment: it wasn't me, but maybe link to existing resources/articles to explain the parts you're not going to explain here.

Comment: Oh I should have said this, too: you would also need to replace the parts' value with `true` and `false` or `1` and `0` based on the values in the table.  Maybe assume you have an `IDictionary<string, bool>` prepared to do this.  Do that and I'll upvote.

Comment: The downvote was mine, and your post looked [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36521295/1), I think no further commentary is necessary there ;) Have an upvote, since you've converted this to a decent answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I could think of was to use a `DataTable`.

This should handle all "happy paths" correctly.  Like it says in the comments you may need to do additional validation to explicitly error out on what you consider invalid input.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Unit test the EvaluateBinaryExpression method.
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("true")); // true
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("false")); // false
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("true or false")); // true
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("false or false")); // false
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("true and false")); // false
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("true and true")); // true
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateBinaryExpression("true and not false")); // false

        //
        // This should give me Ahmed && love && ! Ali which will be true for doc1.

        // TODO: get these values out of the table.
        var doc1Results = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
        {
            { "Ahmed", true },
            { "love", true },
            { "ali", false }
        };

        // Then just call it like this
        Console.Out.WriteLine(EvaluateResults("Ahmed and love and not ali", doc1Results)); // true
    }

    public static bool EvaluateResults(string expression, IDictionary<string, bool> results)
    {
        // TODO validate input expression and results

        // Make sure the expression is padded with whitespace for replacing.
        var replaced = " " + expression + " ";

        foreach (var kvp in results)
        {
            var search = " " + kvp.Key + " ";
            var replacement = " " + kvp.Value.ToString() + " ";
            // TODO make sure casing, etc. doesn't matter.
            replaced = replaced.Replace(search, replacement);
        }

        return EvaluateBinaryExpression(replaced);
    }

    public static bool EvaluateBinaryExpression(string expression)
    {
        // TODO what if this throws an error?
        var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(object));
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null });
        dt.Columns[0].Expression = expression;
        var value = dt.Rows[0][0] as bool?;
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```